# Create Array from Generator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, generator

**I want to create an array from the values of an generator** in JavaScript.
The generator creates a sequence of dynamic length like this

```
function* sequenceGenerator(minVal, maxVal) {
    let currVal = minVal;

    while(currVal < maxVal)
        yield currVal++;
}
```

I want to store those values in an array but using `next()` until the generator is done does not seem to be the best way possible (and looks quite ugly to be honest).

```
var it, curr, arr;

it = sequenceGenerator(100, 1000);
curr = it.next();
arr = [];

while(! curr.done){
    arr.push(curr.value);
}
```

Can I somehow create an array directly from/within the generator? 
If not, can I somehow avoid/hide the loop? Maybe by using `map` or something like that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I found another way

```
var arr = Array.from( sequenceGenerator(min, max) );
```

works aswell.

Answer (score 59):

One short solution might be:

```
let list = [...sequenceGenerator(min, max)]
```

Documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this;

```js
function* sequenceGenerator() {
  let currVal = this.minVal;
  while(currVal <= this.maxVal) yield currVal++;
}
var obj = {minVal: 10, maxVal:20},
    arr;
obj[Symbol.iterator] = sequenceGenerator;
arr = [...obj];
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you asked a very specific question, I am wondering if you are trying to solve a more general problem, i.e. keeping generator results around in a convenient manner. If go, you might try looking at https://github.com/anywhichway/generx. This will actually let you treat the generator like it is an array, i.e. access it using array notation after it has run.

Answer (score 0):

```
{let
  isGen = (genProto => (val => genProto.isPrototypeOf(val)))(
    Object.getPrototypeOf(function*(){}) ),
  iterMthdGen = (() => (function() { return this(); })),
  createAddIterMthdFn = (iterMthdFn => ((obj) =>
    Object.assign(obj, {[Symbol.iterator]: iterMthdFn(), }) )),
  addIterMthdGen = createAddIterMthdFn(iterMthdGen),
  wrapGen = (gen => ({[Symbol.iterator]: gen}))
  g = function*() { for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) yield i; };
// [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 , 9],  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 , 9]
console.log([...wrapGen(g)], [...addIterMthdGen(g)]); }
```

Using this recipes to work with generators. wrapGen is simpliest method.
addIterMthdGen makes generator also an iterable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).